# error: "control may reach end of non-void function"

Tags: c++, glut, bmp

I've been following this video [BMP Loader for GLUT](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O42Fok8ikxU). I keep getting the error "control may reach end of non-void function" on the last bracket. How do I resolve this error? It seems weird to me that if file "fp" is not open one could fclose the file "fp" when it is not open in the first place!

```
#include "Texture.h"

Texture::Texture(void* data, int w, int h, int format) {
glGenTextures(1, &textureID);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, w, h, 0, format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
}

Texture* Texture::loadBMP(const char* filename) {
FILE* fp;
fp = fopen(filename, "r");
if (!fp) {
    cout << filename << "could not be opened!" << endl;
    fclose(fp);
    return NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to add `return` to the end of the function. Function doesn't return anything is file is successfully opened.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer. It works now. Funny the video doesn't have that other return after the return NULL.

Comment: Well that's what happens when you try to learn C++ from online "tuts" recorded by randoms.

Answer (score 1):

It's what it says: it is possible for the program to reach the end of `loadBMP` without having `return`'d anything.

You need to decide what you want to return from this function when the file was opened successfully.